# How to get blob from HTMLAudioElement?

Tags: javascript, media-source

I know that I can use `fetch()` but this will trigger new HTTP request - while in memory I already have audio that I want to store in IndexedDB. I tried:

```
new Blob(audio)
```

And get:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable.`

Also [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) does not a have method such as `blob()`.

I thought about `MediaSource` but currently it is not supports ogg:

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"')
```

It return `false`.

Comment: use file reader api

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to do it in reverse: fetch into Blob, then build Audio element from it?

Comment: @raina77ow I need to use `new Audio(src).play()` for fastest playing - because this is the only way I know how to *stream* audio, with `fetch()` I need to wait before fully downloaded.

Comment: But you still need to wait for it to be fully downloaded to be stored, no? Anyway, is it possible to implement DASH-like approach in your case?

Comment: @raina77ow I have `.onended` event catched after the end of playing - here my audio already downloaded. What is DASH?

Comment: [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP). So all the files always are played (and streamed) from the beginning to the end.

Comment: @AshokShah I did not find how to use it with `HTMLAudioElement` from memory https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader, what was your idea?

Comment: @raina77ow as I [understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video) DASH is `Media Source Extension API` which is currently does not works with `ogg`.

Comment: you can get blob data directly with mp3 url. https://staxmanade.com/2015/11/how-to-base64-and-save-a-binary-audio-file-to-local-storage-and-play-it-back-in-the-browser/

Comment: @AshokShah from this article: `Use fetch api we can easily get at the blob()`. I cannot use `fetch()` because streaming available only using `new Audio()`, or with `fetch()` after playing I will make HTTP call twice.

Comment: It sounds like you want the MediaRecorder interface?  Unclear really... what's the actual source for this audio element?  Why can't you capture data directly from it?

Comment: @Brad audio from IndexedDB.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich You said you want to *store* audio in IndexedDB.  Is it from the DB, or do you want to store it there?  Which is it?

Comment: @Brad, sorry, client get audio from S3, store in IndexedDB for future playing.

Comment: Why not let browser caching handle this all on its own?

Comment: @Brad as I understand `new Audio(src)` will be cached only when it is completely played - because creating HTMLAudioElement with src will prefetch only a few seconds, but I need to cache full file.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich No, the whole file will be cached if it's downloaded and the caching headers allow it to be.  Just let the browser do its job.

Comment: @Brad you said `if it's downloaded`, but looks like `new Audio(src)` does not download file fully without playing to the end.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich That depends on the browser.  Some will, some won't.  What's the issue?  Are you trying to store it for offline usage?

Comment: @Brad I need to play audio offline, in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and in the future Edge. This is for my WebExtension. Caching already almost implemented by using IndexedDB - this is my first experience with this database, just asked this question for optimization.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Use the Cache interface instead.  https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: @Brad Why Cache in lieu of IndexedDB?